# How to phrase a worldwide location in English?

Tags: geography

I have an online form where a user would usually submit a specific location in a field, e.g. Moscow, Berlin, New York, Paris. But sometimes there is no specific city location, for instance for a seminar that takes place "online" or a web screening.

I want to enable the users to enter the "worldwide" case. What are typical phrases in English for that to catch? Planet, www, online, internet, worldwide, anywhere. Can you imagine up more suitable candidates? Are you aware of any existing English geo-databases with entries for the worldwide location case?

Comment: It completely depends on what you want to use the expression for, but given your example, _on-line_ would be just fine, I think. In job descriptions that involve (mostly) remote work, instead of a specific location, I have seen _virtual_ mentioned as the location. You might consider that too.

Comment: Maybe "Multiple locations". That could cover a video linked event, or a number of things happening in different places but considered to be one event, and doesn't imply the internet was involved.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "worldwide location" is contradictory. If the users are online, I would simply use the word **online**.

Answer (score 1):

Example: If you overlook The Continent of Africa, It will have worldwide implications or global implications (which ever you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative to worldwide would be **global**:

> adjective
>   1. pertaining to the whole world; worldwide; universal:

[Reference.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/global)

Comment: Very good! Note that it isn't either or for me, I am interested in any phrase a user might type in.